# Can't add layered navigation block into CMS page

Tags: magento, filter, layer

I need to show new products on a CMS page. It works fine. Then I need to add the layered navigation block on the left to filter out the selection. But it never works. I add this code into the **Layout Update XML** field:

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

I tried with block type core/template, but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know why it never works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not call layer navigation using this type of code.For layer navigation on cms yo
u need a category or if you do  not have category then put root category id,whose id 2(Default category)
here details of link

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242296#21242296https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242296#21242296)