# Layered Navigation don't appear in a CMS Page

Tags: php, magento

i already read a lot of posts here and in other forums about it, but none works to me,
i have a custom product list asked new-prod-list.phtml, and i call it on a cms page

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/new-prod-list.phtml"}}
```

my xml update layout is like this (2 columns left)

```
<reference name="left"> 
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-"  template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

When i open the page www.site.com.br/new-prod-list the products appear but the sidebar come empty.

Can someone help me?

I change to this, but still not working

```
<reference name="left">
        <!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
                <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
        </block>
</reference>

<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/new-prod-list.phtml">

                <!-- Product List View -->
                <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>

        </block>
</reference>
```

Already tried this soluctions, but without sucess:

[CMS page with layered navigation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242296#21242296)

http://www.webdesign-gm.co.uk/news/web-design/magento-web-design/layered-navigation-on-home-page-or-any-cms-page-magento.php

Comment: Helllo,gabrielbuzzi can you please check details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767549/cant-add-layered-navigation-block-into-cms-page/21770662#21770662

Comment: @AmitBera I tried it, use the code that pass that with my root category, but still dont adding the layered navigation.

Comment: please check properly add xml in code

Comment: @AmitBera I edit my post with the code i inserted, but still not working.