# Layered navigation on homepage in magento 1.9 Call to a member function load() on a non-object in Error Occured

Tags: php, magento, layered-navigation

I am trying to show a layered navigation on homepage. I m using magento 1.9.0. and inserted following xml in `Layout Update XML`

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Then in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\layer.php` modified function `getCurrentCategory()` as follows to get root category on home-page:

```
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getData(’current_category’);
    if (is_null($category)) {
        if ($category = Mage::registry(’current_category’)) {
            $this->setData(’current_category’, $category);
        }
        else {
            $category = false;
            $this->setData(’current_category’, $category);
        }
    }

    // added to make this work for front page:
    if(is_null($category) || $category == false) {
        $home_category = Mage::getModel(’catalog/category’)->load(4); //number must correspond to ‘all products page’ category
        $this->setData(’current_category’, $home_category);
        $category = $this->getData(’current_category’);

        return $category;

    }

    //end addition

    return $category; 
}
```

But Following error has occurred:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer.php on line 174

Please help.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767549/cant-add-layered-navigation-block-into-cms-page/21770662#21770662

Comment: I have checked your answer link but following error has occured.Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\View.php on line 134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add the complete block like this:

```
 <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.layer.filter.view" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.left.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
```

Without the render it doesn't function