# Paging on products on a CMS page - Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have created a page via CMS, which lists products using: 
{{block type = "catalog / product_list" category_id = "2" template = "catalog / product / list.phtml"}}

However, this listing does not have a pagination.

And as I am new to magento, do not know how to include it.

I know there are already some questions about this doubt. 
for example:
[CMS page with layered navigation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242296#21242296)

however, were not successful for me.

if anyone has any idea or guidance.

Appreciate the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paulo,gincalves,it try my blog ,then check in list.phtml tollbar is called not /ya `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` and pager in tollbar.phtml

Comment: Such a simple thing! : D 
It is that I am still a beginner in magento. 
The previous developer had commented code.