# Magento. Layered navigation is not showing

Tags: php, magento, layered-navigation

I have CMS page which outputs list of all products. It uses block created by custom extension.

The problem is that it does not output Layered Navigation filters.

Here is CMS page Layout update:

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="wtc_allproducts/list" name="allproducts" template="wtc/allproducts/list.phtml">

    <!-- Layered Navigation Block; setCategoryId sets id of Root category -->
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
      <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
    </block>

    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
      <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>

    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

**wtc/allproducts/list.phtml** code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="infoblock">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_collectionSize = $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="category-products">
      <div class="row">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>

        <?php foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>

          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="brand product-item">
               <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
              <p><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></p>

              <div class="price"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></div>

              <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <input type="image" class="button btn-cart" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/assets/addtocart.png'); ?>" style="height: 34px;" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
              <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
              <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- /.brand.product-item -->
          </div><!-- /.col-xs-3 -->
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </div><!-- /.row -->

      <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
      </div><!-- /.toolbar-bottom -->

    </div><!-- /.category-products -->
  </div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**WTC/AllProducts/Block/List.php** code:

```
<?php

class WTC_AllProducts_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
  protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'catalog/product_list_toolbar';

  protected $_allProductsCollection;

  protected function _getAllProductsCollection()
  {
    if (is_null($this->_allProductsCollection)) {
      $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');

      $this->_allProductsCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

      $this->getToolbarBlock()->removeOrderFromAvailableOrders('position');
      $this->getToolbarBlock()->removeOrderFromAvailableOrders('aitmanufacturers_sort');

      $this->_allProductsCollection->setPage(
        $this->getToolbarBlock()->getCurrentPage(),
        $this->getToolbarBlock()->getLimit()
      );
    }

    return $this->_allProductsCollection;
  }

  public function getAllProductsCollection()
  {
    return $this->_getAllProductsCollection();
  }


  public function getMode()
  {
    return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

    // called prepare sortable parameters
    $collection = $this->_getAllProductsCollection();

    // use sortable parameters
    if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
      $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
    }
    if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
      $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
    }
    if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
      $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
    }
    if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
      $toolbar->setModes($modes);
    }

    // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
    $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

    $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
      'collection' => $this->_getAllProductsCollection()
    ));

    $this->setProductCollection($collection);

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }

  public function getToolbarBlock()
  {
    if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
      if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
        return $block;
      }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
    return $block;
  }

  public function getToolbarHtml()
  {
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
  }

  public function setCollection($collection)
  {
    $this->_allProductsCollection = $collection;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

I don't see where is my mistake.

Comment: Does the category_id 2 set as "Is Anchor" ?

Comment: Did you perform indexing also?

Comment: Yes, indexing performed.

Comment: change "catalog.leftnav" to some other name both in list.phtml and layout xml files, flush cache and then check

Comment: I changed to "layered_filters" - no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **if** statement in **catalog/layer/view.phtml** left by previous programmer, which disallowed to show layered navigation filters if page has an URL. :/ Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have not calling layer navigation in xml file.Please check more in 
[CMS page with layered navigation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242388#21242388)

Comment: I'm calling it:

`<!-- Layered Navigation Block; setCategoryId sets id of Root category -->
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
      <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
    </block>`

Answer (score 0):

You have called `layerd navigation block` under `<content>` tag.

Call that block under `<reference name="left">` or `<reference name="right">` tag.