# Custom products page - How to add layered navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have created a cms that displays all special price products, using:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_special" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="3" num_products="0"}}
```

I'd like to add layered navigation to the left bar of the page. I have read some posts about this issue, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working/21242296#21242296) or [this one](http://www.noamdesign.com/magento-include-layered-navigation-in-cms-page-listing-products/). But when I add layered navigation throught xml, I'm getting the follown error

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php on line 134**

I'm using magento 1.9.0.1 and this is a fresh installation.

What does this error means and how can I fix it? 
Is there something else I could try to display layered navigation in this page?

**edit:**

here's the xml code, I used:

```
<reference name="left">
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: show your xml code .. Make your question more detail

Comment: I have used  the code as it's described in the links I posted. I have also tried other versions of xml code, in some cases the code simply doesn't work at all, and in som other cases I'm getting the error.

I posted some xml code, that might be useful to you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't delved into 1.9.0 as we're still waiting for bug-fixes to roll out (there are bound to be some bugs that got released with the initial new version) but the problem you're running into is related to the underlying technology (PHP and OOP) where you are attempting to reference an object which has not yet been instantiated.

You'll have to look into the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php` file to see why this error is being thrown; it's expecting an object to have been instantiated which does not exist within the scope of the running program.